# How to get dropdown option in schema using autoform?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I want to get the dropdown options from another collection (i.e MyCollection). In this collection i have all the option values (i.e options). I am using collection2 package i want to get all the options in schema only not using helper.

Define Collection :

```
MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');
```

collection structure :

```
{
    options : [A, B, C, D, E, F]
}
```

collection2 schema :

```
some-schema = new SimpleSchema({

     dropdown : {
         type : String,
         label : "Select One",
         autoform : {
               options: /*....*/
         }
     }
});
```

html :

```
{{#autoForm schema='some-schema' id='some-id' type="method" meteormethod="some-method"}}
    {{> afQuickField name='dropdown'}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Any Suggestion...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function that will be executed in a reactive computation to dynamically compute the list of available options.

```
SomeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  [...]
  dropdown : {
    type : String,
    label : "Select One",
    autoform : {
      options: function(){
        var doc = MyCollection.findOne();
        var docOptions = doc && doc.options;
        return _.map(docOptions, function(value){
          return {
            label: value,
            value: value
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
  [...]
});
```

You can actually set options in an AutoForm select using many different ways, see for yourself : https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#what-are-the-various-ways-i-can-specify-options-for-a-select-radio-group-or-checkbox-group

Comment: @saimeunt..first of all thanxx..I tried what you said but `var doc = MyCollection.findOne(); and ` **doc** is coming undefined. My scheme file location is in **both/schema.js** . I am not using publish-subscribe technique between client-server. whenever need data from db i make a server call using **Meteor.call(...)**. what are the possible ways...

Comment: I don't understand not using pub-sub... I think you need to publish your collection data, and then subscribe to it on the client, so that examples like this will work for you

Comment: @iamhimadri I know this is years later, but did you try `using findOne({});` instead?